# Run-Time Error 7866 with OpenCurrentDatabase

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

When I run the code below I get Run-Time Error `7866`:

**Microsoft Access can't open the database because it is missing or opened exclusively by another user, or it is not an ADP file.**

The error is thrown on this line
`db.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\QE9142\Desktop\VES Mgmt Reports ONLY.mdb"`

I am trying to open an Access database that is saved on my desktop through Excel.

```
Sub Task()

Dim db As Access.Application
Dim strDB As String
Set db = New Access.Application
db.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\QE9142\Desktop\VES Mgmt Reports ONLY.mdb"
db.Application.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Which version of Office?

Comment: Access 2016 is what I am using.

Comment: How did you create the file?

Comment: The excel file was made by my boss (had no code before I started working on the workbook). The access database was made before I started at working for my boss.

Comment: Do you want to open db and give control to user?

Comment: Yes, Basically I want to open the database and export a form to excel. I copied the code from a similar project but it throws the run time error.

Comment: So open db and user then manually manages the export? Is the db split?

Comment: I don't think the db is split, and I am considering just exporting the form manually.

Comment: Actually, would not export form - export data. If you want Excel to pull data, then have it pull from table or query. But need to get past this error first. I tested code with MDB and ACCDB files on desktop and cannot replicate error.

Comment: Have you checked path and filename? Do you have access to the desktop of user QE9142?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't replicate this error, but when the code exits, so does Access.

Insert a STOP or other event that will hold the code:

```vb
Sub Task()

    Dim db As Access.Application
    Dim strDB As String

    Set db = New Access.Application
    db.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\QE9142\Desktop\VES Mgmt Reports ONLY.mdb"
    db.Application.Visible = True
    Stop    

End Sub
```

As for the error, try opening the mdb in Access and save it as an *accdb* file (Access 2007 format).

Comment: I can't save the database because it says it is in use even though I'm the only user in the database.

Comment: I think Gustav is suggesting you convert the file to ACCDB then run your code.

Answer (score 0):

If user should take control of database once opened, don't see need for connection object. Use Shell command to simply open database file. Then user can do whatever they want with it.

`Shell "cmd /c " & Chr(34) & "C:\Users\QE9142\Desktop\VES Mgmt Reports ONLY.mdb" & Chr(34)`