# VBScript reads MDB - it is not an ADP file

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbscript

I am very new to VBS and am trying to call a vba macro from a MDB file.  My friend Google showed this piece of code many times, [Microsoft's office site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.run) included.

However, it throws error saying "***Microsoft Access can't open the database because it is missing, or opened exclusively by another user, or it is not an ADP file.***" I am positively sure the db file is there and it is not opened. Can you anyone tell me why the code does not work? How can I convert MDB file to ADP?

```
set appAccess = createobject("Access.application")
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("SAME.MDB")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run-Time Error 7866 with OpenCurrentDatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275122/run-time-error-7866-with-opencurrentdatabase)

Comment: @Lankymart I believe there are similar questions like the one you just posted. But there was no answer to that question.

Comment: At this point ADP is pretty much dead.

Comment: Have a look at [Open multiple Access 2010 databases](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e46eb0f5-499a-4c42-900d-2697f192ec87/open-multiple-access-2010-databases?forum=accessdev) for a **possible** explanation plus solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to resolve the error. But I found a workaround using powershell instead of VBS

```
    $app = New-Object -comobject Access.Application
    $app.OpenCurrentDatabase("SAME.MDB")
    $app.run("mainrun")
    $app.CloseCurrentDatabase()
```